# Angular browser url to reflect with search params passing through the http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My single page app have a search page with lot of filters. It workes as REST api calls on each search request. My requirement is to update the browser url on every search but my controller should'nt get refreshed. 
This is my present url
http://www.example.com/#/search_result

On each search request my url should change into.

```
http://www.example.com/#/search_result/?keyword=tagar

http://www.example.com/#/search_result/?keyword=tagar&stage=[70]&value_from=0

http://www.example.com/#/search_result/?keyword=city=[6003]&country=[223]&keyword=dubai&stage=[10,20]&value_from=0
```

Like wise there will be lot of possiblility.

The objective of this problem is if I enter the direct url of a search it should shows the search result.

Any help please.

Comment: For entering direct url, use $routeProvider with $routeParams. Parse the query, call REST service then load your controller. After that, each time change the query, update your browser url with $location.path('/newValue')

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used the tag 'angular-ui-router', you could define your url using the UrlMatcher api. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

This means that the state won't change. Only the state parameters will :)

UPDATE:
It's a bit ugly, but it should work :) My recommendation is that you put this in a directive. Keep in mind that you get tight coupling this way.

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if(fromState.name === 'search-result' && toState.name === 'search-result'){
            ev.preventDefault();
            // add the logic to update the results based on toParams
        }
    });`

Comment: can you please help me with the wild card that to be used in $routProvider that can accpet any url like above. My current code is like $routeProvider.when('/search_result', { ... ....

Comment: ui-router offers the option: 'reloadOnSearch: false' for states, which disables transitions. 

The thing is that you cannot trigger the call to the backend unless the controller is refreshed (in case the logic for communicating is there).

If you don't want to refresh the controller, you could add a handler to '$stateChangeStart' and put the call there. I'll edit the post with the details.